# How do you fix: "TypeError: 'Mob' object is not subscriptable" in pygame?

Tags: pygame, python-3.7

I am making a platformer game in pygame. I am in the process of adding a mob to the level. I assumed it would be the same as adding a platform, but that is clearly not the case. I keep getting this error: 
"TypeError: 'Mob' object is not subscriptable". (Full error at bottom). Can anyone fix this and explain? NOTE: I'm importing a lot of files so there will be a lot of imports.

```py
    import pygame
    from spritesheet_functions import SpriteSheet

    SLIME_WALK = (52, 125, 50, 28)


    class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        """ Mobs the player will encounter in the level. """

        def __init__(self, sprite_sheet_data):
            """ Mob constructor. Assumes constructed with 
            user passing in
            an array of 5 numbers like what's defined at the 
            top of this
            code. """

        super().__init__()

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet('enemies.png')

        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(sprite_sheet_data[0],
                                            sprite_sheet_data[1],
                                            sprite_sheet_data[2],
                                            sprite_sheet_data[3])

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()



    import pygame
    from os import path
    from spritesheet_functions import SpriteSheet
    import constants
    import platforms
    import mobs

    class Level(object):

        def __init__(self, player):
           # Lists of sprites used in all levels. Add or remove
           # lists as needed for your game.
           self.platform_list = None
           self.enemy_list = None

           # Background image
           self.background = None
           # How far this world has been scrolled left/right
           self.world_shift = 0
           self.level_limit = -1000
           self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
           self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
           self.player = player

           # Update everything on this level
           def update(self):
           """ Update everything in this level."""
           self.platform_list.update()
           self.enemy_list.update()

        def draw(self, screen):
            """ Draw everything on this level. """

            # Draw the background
            # We don't shift the background as much as the 
            sprites are shifted
            # to give a feeling of depth.
            screen.fill(constants.BLUE)
            screen.blit(self.background.sprite_sheet, 
            (self.world_shift // 3, 0))

            # Draw all the sprite lists that we have
            self.platform_list.draw(screen)
            self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

        def shift_world(self, shift_x):
            """ When the user moves left/right and we need 
            to scroll everything: """

            # Keep track of the shift amount
            self.world_shift += shift_x

            # Go through all the sprite lists and shift
            for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += shift_x

            for enemy in self.enemy_list:
                enemy.rect.x += shift_x


    # Create platforms and mobs for the level
    class Level01(Level):
        """ Definition for level 1. """

        def __init__(self, player):
        """ Create level 1. """

            # Call the parent constructor
             Level.__init__(self, player)

            self.background = SpriteSheet('background_01.png')
            self.background.sprite_sheet.set_colorkey(constants.WHITE)
            self.level_limit = -2500

            # Array with type of platform, and x, y location of the 
            platform.
            level_blocks = [[platforms.GRASS_LEFT, 500, 500],
                            [platforms.GRASS_MIDDLE, 570, 500],
                            [platforms.GRASS_RIGHT, 640, 500],
                            [platforms.GRASS_LEFT, 800, 400],
                            [platforms.GRASS_MIDDLE, 870, 400],
                            [platforms.GRASS_RIGHT, 940, 400],
                            [platforms.GRASS_LEFT, 1000, 500],
                            [platforms.GRASS_MIDDLE, 1070, 500],
                            [platforms.GRASS_RIGHT, 1140, 500],
                            [platforms.STONE_PLATFORM_LEFT, 1120, 280],
                            [platforms.STONE_PLATFORM_MIDDLE, 1190, 
                             280],
                            [platforms.STONE_PLATFORM_RIGHT, 1260, 
                             280],
                           ]

            # Array with type of mob, and x, y location of the mob
            level_enemies = [[mobs.SLIME_WALK, 100, 400]]

            # Go through the array above and add platforms
            for platform in level_blocks:
                block = platforms.Platform(platform[0])
                block.rect.x = platform[1]
                block.rect.y = platform[2]
                block.player = self.player
                self.platform_list.add(block)

             # Go through the array above and add mobs
             for enemy in level_enemies:
                enemy = mobs.Mob(enemy[0])
                enemy.rect.x = enemy[1]
                enemy.rect.y = enemy[2]
                enemy.player = self.player
                self.platform_list.add(enemy)
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File 
    "/Users//PycharmProjects/Platformer/platform_scroller.py", 
    line 107, in <module>
        main()
        File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Platformer/platform_scroller.py", line 23, in main
    level_list = [levels.Level01(player), levels.Level02(player)]
        File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Platformer/levels.py", line 107, in __init__
    enemy = mobs.Mob(enemy[0])
        File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Platformer/mobs.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(sprite_sheet_data[0],
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Can you mark what line the error is occurring on?

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `platform` variable?

Comment: Please can you stop tagging as PyCharm.

Comment: It's fine I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Array with type of mob, and x, y location of the mob
level_enemies = [mobs.SLIME_WALK, 100, 400]

# Go through the array above and add mobs
    for enemy in level_enemies:
        enemy = mobs.Mob(enemy[0])
        enemy.rect.x = enemy[1]
        enemy.rect.y = enemy[2]
        enemy.player = self.player
        self.platform_list.add(enemy)
```

In this code block, `enemy` refers to `mob.SLIME_WALK`, `100`, and then `400`. Those are `ints` and cannot be subscripted.

Perhaps you meant to declare `level_enemies` as:

```py
level_enemies = [[mobs.SLIME_WALK, 100, 400]]
```

Comment: ```enemy = mobs.Mob(enemy[0])``` Make that first ```enemy``` have a different variable name.